# USA Advance Parole expiring Jan 15th, planned December 16th to Jan 6th Schengen trip

Tags: usa, schengen-visas

My trip consists of Spain, Italy, Croatia, Austria. USA Advance Parole expiring Jan 15th, I planned a Schengen trip from December 16th to January 6th.

Schengen visa scheduled at the Spanish Houston Consulate on Monday. Would they decline as my Parole is ending within 3 months of my planned return date?

France does not appear to have that condition. Alternatively, should I apply at the French consulate (interview scheduled on October 16th)?

Should I try both or ignore Spain and only try France? I can replan my travel to include Paris and enter first there (though it appears very costly now)?

Comment: When does your *passport* expire?

Answer (score 2):

A Schengen visa must be applied for at the Consulate of the country where you will spend the most time. If the time is spent in equally all countries, the country of arrival. France is not in your itinerary – there's no way for you to get a Schengen visa from them, or at least without deception.

If your Advance Parole is valid until after your return, isn't that enough for the visa...?

Comment: "or at least without deception": or a change of itinerary.

Answer (score 0):

My Passport is valid till 2028. But the condition written in spain Consulate kind of put me in trouble - [image: highlighted comment]

Permit to return to the United States of America in the form of a Residence Card, or a Student/work visa, stamped on the passport, or parole. Residence Card or US visa must be valid at least three months beyond the expected length of stay in the Schengen area. - Can you please read this for me ...Means Visa expiry date should be my arrival date in USA+90 days ?

in the mean time i took an appointment at France consulate which does not have the above condition.

i booked my Ticket to Paris with award tickets which i can cancel later too, worst come i need to include France in trip and remove Spain this time .

Comment: Why are you using a second account to answer your own question?

Comment: You can [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts.